# yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token found character '\t' that cannot start any token

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to create node and mongo service and run them in the same network using the docker compose file but it showing me this error "yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token" when i run docker-compose build command

can anyone please help me.

this is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
    node:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: node.dockerfile
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        networks: 
            - nodeapp-network
    mongodb:
        image: mongo
        networks: 
            - nodeapp-network

networks: 
  nodeapp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 80):

Use spaces instead of tabs and the error will not persist

Answer (score 31):

You may be using "tab" to indent your YAML file.

The "tab" is not permitted by the YAML specs:

> To maintain portability, tab characters must not be used in
>   indentation, since different systems treat tabs differently. Note that
>   most modern editors may be configured so that pressing the tab key
>   results in the insertion of an appropriate number of spaces.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using xcode to open the .ymlfile then check this out:

In case ur xCode settings configured for text editing with tab, then you can it change it to spaces like this:

Go to xCode preference using `cmd + ,`

[image]